Virtual Path handling in tcl 8.6.6 with auto_path
I am new to tcl VFS. I am trying to add local path as virtual path using auto_path variable. Same was working with tcl 8.4 and was able to load the tclIndex from that path. However, tcl8.6.6 is not working and not able to load tclIndex automatically.
Is the mechanism different in tcl8.6? Please help.
Adding virtual path to auto_path :
lappend auto_path /virtualFS

I tried below method as well
lappend auto_path [file join [file dirname [file normalize [info script]]]] /virtualFS]

I have a C API as well which append path to the auto_path variable.
 if(Tcl_Eval(interp,"global auto_path; lappend auto_path [file join [file dirname [file normalize [info script]]] /virtualFS]"))

But none of the above is working.

I don't think there's been any meaningful changes to what auto_path does since 1990 other than it being used also for package discovery. How the initial value is set has changed a bit, but appending to it should work the same as always.

IDK IIRC, but didn’t the underlying VFS change (for the better) in 8.6? If you are still sourcing the older VFS that may be causing an issue...

Thanks for all replies. My tclIndex is inside mydir which I am trying to use as virtualFS. Adding this virtualFS in the auto_path but I am not sure how would I do the mapping of mydir to virtualFS

Also Please note that I am using zlib to get the content of tclIndex from virtualFS. I have mapped the compressed data of the file mydir/tclIndex to filename /virtualFS/tclIndex.
